# Is my Lenovo ThinkPad overheating most likely causes Windows 10 freeze?

Tags: freeze, window

Recently, after my Lenovo ThinkPad fan was cleaned in repair shop and CPU thermal compound (gel) changed. At some point in time laptop freezes completely and only hard reset makes it alive again. Can it be bad quality of sevice at repair shop due to the following fact:

Intel max CPU temperature is 72C. My CPU temp is quite close to it and some times hit 80C.

[image]

[image]

Can it be concluded that freeze caused by overheating?

How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Sounds like whom ever repaired your laptop did a bad job, get a refund, and find somebody better to fix the problem the other guys created

Comment: They should give you a refund or fix it properly. Alternatively, it's not too difficult to do yourself (should you want details, just ask). Most likely the thermal compound has not been properly applied.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that an overheating computer is likely to cause freezes. Source: http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2006/jul/27/guardianweeklytechnologysection4 (and many fora suggest the same).

Considering your computer gets too hot even beyond the recommended temperature specified by Intel, there is a reasonable chance you are causing damage to your CPU.

It is clear that the computer repair shop messed up. This means that they should either fix it properly or give you a refund. Depending on the specific model you have, the repair should not be too complicated, so doing it yourself is an option as well. In any case, it should be easy to find someone who can do it.

If you specify your model, I could point you to the right instruction manual and tell you how easy the fix would be to do yourself. If you don't dare to do it yourself, perhaps let a handy colleague or friend do it with help of the manual.

With this model, it is not difficult to do the repair yourself. Look for "1060 Fan assembly" in the pdf from the following link: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/docs/migr-75051
There are plenty tutorials how to apply thermal paste on the internet, just beware that you only have to use a tiny bit.

Comment: Lenovo 03193ug. Repair shop offered to upgrade my i3 to i5 for free. Will it help or worsen the situation?

Comment: If they change it to for instance an i5-540m the difference will be small. The CPU's are almost identical, have a TDP of 35 Watts. Due to the higher clock frequency during turbo boost, the i5 might get slightly hotter. However, I think your situation is caused by bad thermal paste application and has nothing to do with the processor. If they fix it properly, your problems should be over whether or not they replace the CPU.